# print png with zebra imz220 - android

Tags: android, bluetooth, zebra-printers

I'm having an issue printing png assets to a zebra imz220 printer, its going to be used to print receipts from an android tablet and a logo is required to be printed at the top of the printout. when printing the image i get a string output instead of the image. I tried the following stackoverflow post as i cant seem to find any documentation on how to do it - [print image via bluetooth printer prints string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26100430/print-image-via-bluetooth-printer-prints-string/29383314#)

```
package com.example.gareth.myzebraprinter;

import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.zebra.sdk.comm.BluetoothConnection;
import com.zebra.sdk.comm.Connection;
import com.zebra.sdk.comm.ConnectionException;
import com.zebra.sdk.graphics.ZebraImageFactory;
import com.zebra.sdk.graphics.ZebraImageI;
import com.zebra.sdk.printer.PrinterLanguage;
import com.zebra.sdk.printer.ZebraPrinter;
import com.zebra.sdk.printer.ZebraPrinterFactory;
import com.zebra.sdk.printer.ZebraPrinterLanguageUnknownException;
import com.zebra.sdk.util.internal.Base64;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ZebraPrinter zebraPrinter;
    private Connection connection;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        connect();
        printTest();
    }

    private void printTest(){

        if(zebraPrinter != null){

            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("ic_launcher.png");
                ZebraImageI zebraImageI = ZebraImageFactory.getImage(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream));
                zebraPrinter.printImage(zebraImageI,250,0,0,-1,false);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ConnectionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

//            byte[] rcpt =  "------------\n\r test test test".getBytes();
//            try {
//                connection.write(rcpt);
//            } catch (ConnectionException e) {
//                Log.e("printTest",e.getMessage());
//            }
        }
    }

    private void connect(){


        connection = new BluetoothConnection("AC3FA41EF22E");

        try
        {
            connection.open();
        }
        catch (ConnectionException ex)
        {
            Log.e("connect","ConnectionException " + ex.getMessage());
            mSleeper.sleep(1000);
            closeConnection();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("connect","Exception "+ex.getMessage());
        }

        try
        {
            zebraPrinter = ZebraPrinterFactory.getInstance(connection);
            PrinterLanguage pl = zebraPrinter.getPrinterControlLanguage();
            Log.i("PrinterPanguage",pl.toString());
        }
        catch (ConnectionException ex)
        {
           Log.e("connect","ConnectionException " + ex.getMessage());
            zebraPrinter = null;
            mSleeper.sleep(1000);
            closeConnection();
        } catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("connect","Exception " + ex.getMessage());
            zebraPrinter = null;
            mSleeper.sleep(1000);
            closeConnection();
        }
    }

    private void closeConnection(){

        if(connection != null){
            try
            {
                connection.close();
            }
            catch (ConnectionException exx)
            {
                Log.e("closeConnection", exx.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm printing with the below code in a RW420 Zebra printer

```
Connection connection = new BluetoothConnection("MAC_ADDRESS_HERE");
connection.open();

//reset margin
//ref https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=forums&topic=021407fb4efb3012e55595f77007e8a
connection.write("! U1 JOURNAL\r\n! U1 SETFF 100 2\r\n".getBytes());

Bitmap bitmapToPrint = /*GET_YOUR_BITMAP*/
ZebraPrinter printer = ZebraPrinterFactory.getInstance(connection);
ZebraImageAndroid zebraImageToPrint = new ZebraImageAndroid(bitmapToPrint);
printer.printImage(zebraImageToPrint, 0, 0, -1, -1, false);
```

Check you print method, use -1 -1 to width and height parameter to mantain the original width and height of the Bitmap

Answer (score 0):

There's another way:

```
  if(conZebra.isConnected()) {
    int widthOfImageInBytes = (bitmap.getWidth() + 7) / 8;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    baos.write(("! 0 200 200 "
                + bitmap.getHeight()
                + " 1\r\nCG "
                + String.valueOf(widthOfImageInBytes)
                + String.valueOf(" ")
                + String.valueOf(bitmap.getHeight())
                + String.valueOf(" ")
                + String.valueOf(0)
                + String.valueOf(" ")
                + String.valueOf(0)
                + String.valueOf(" ")).getBytes());
    conZebra.write(baos.toByteArray());
    OutputStream compressedBitmapOutputStreamCpcl = new CompressedBitmapOutputStreamCpcl(conZebra);
    DitheredImageProvider.getDitheredImage(bitmap, compressedBitmapOutputStreamCpcl);
    compressedBitmapOutputStreamCpcl.close();
    conZebra.write("\r\nFORM\r\nPRINT\r\n".getBytes());
    //printer.getGraphicsUtil().printImage(bitmap, 0, 0, -1, -1, false);
    Utils.DebugLog(Utils.TAG_PRINTERMODULE, "Bitmap enviado...");
} else {
    Utils.DebugLog(Utils.TAG_PRINTERMODULE, "La impresora no est� conectada, imprimirBitmap() fall�");
}
```